# how do I make a search box that accepts regular expression to search data?

Tags: javascript, regex, sapui5

If the user enters " Mil* " then the search should return "Milk", "Milk Cake", "Milk sweet", "Milky bar chocolate"... 
I'm trying to make a SAP UI5 Application, where the filter understands regular expression. Then the result is displayed in a table.

```
 var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
                        path     : "ProductName", 
                        operator : CustomFilterToAcceptRegEx,
                        value1   : "Milk"
                    });
```

I can't think of anyway to do this. Any advice would be helpful. 
I'm totally new to javascript & SAP UI5

Comment: `^Mil.*` will match any string starting with `Mil`. Perhaps you'd want some finer nuances but we need more input and expected output then.

Comment: What kind of model are you using? v2.ODataModel? JSONModel?

Answer (score 2):

Your code above cannot work because the operator you passed is absolutely invalid, see the [API docs for sap.ui.model.Filter](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Filter.html). Only use one of the allowed [FilterOperators](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.html). Here is an example:

```
var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
    path     : "ProductName", 
    operator : sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains,
    value1   : "Milk"
});
```

The example above matches "*Milk*", that means the user does not need to use the "*" and can instead enter "Milk" into the (search) field.

In case you want to allow something like "M*lk" you could use something like this:

```
var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
    path     : "ProductName", 
    test     : function(oValue){ 
        //do something
    },
    value1   : "Milk"
});
```

The [Constructor Details of sap.ui.model.Filter](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Filter.html) tell yo how to implement the **oFilterInfo.test** function:

> function which is used to filter the items which should return a boolean value to indicate whether the current item is preserved

However, be careful with OData, because the ODataModel is actually a server side model. If you are using OData in combination with the SAP Gateway the a "freetext" search might be better than using a filter. The SAP GW recognizes the query param "search" which is used for free text search. The implementation of the GW service should then handle the param correctly...

Also, make sure to really understand how a regex in javascript works. Here is an example:

```
RegExp(".*world.*", "g").test("hello world");   // true
```

Also think about how to escape the search string so that it is a valid regex. You cannot simply pass in any string you receive from the search box. So lear how regex work is javascript first before you continue...